# JavaFX: Exception handling in an editable TextFieldTableCell

Tags: java, javafx

My TableView is editable, so I can update the price and quantity directly from the table without pressing any button. My price and quantity are Integers so, how can I handle an exception when I enter a String value? I want my program to show a DialogPane with a message or something like that?

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.util.converter.IntegerStringConverter;
import model.Produs;
import service.Service;
import validator.ValidationException;

import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class ControllerAdmin implements Initializable  {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Produs> table;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Produs, String> colNume;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Produs, Integer> colPret;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Produs, Integer> colCantitate;

    @FXML
    private TextField lblNume;

    @FXML
    private TextField lblCant;

    @FXML
    private TextField lblPret;

    private ObservableList<Produs> observableList;

    private Service service;
    public ControllerAdmin(){}
    public void setService(Service service){
        this.service=service;
        observableList = FXCollections.observableList(StreamSupport.stream(service.getAllProducts().spliterator(), false).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        observableList.remove(new Produs("b",2,2));
        loadTables();
    }

    private void loadTables() {
        table.setItems(observableList);
        table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observer, oldData, newData) -> showDetails(newData));
        table.setEditable(true);
        colPret.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));
        colCantitate.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));


    }

    private void showDetails(Produs t) {if(t!=null){
        lblNume.setText(t.getDenumire());
        lblCant.setText(String.valueOf(t.getCantitate()));
        lblPret.setText(String.valueOf(t.getPret()));
    }

    }

    public void clickAdd(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            service.saveProduct(new Produs(lblNume.getText(), Integer.parseInt(lblPret.getText()), Integer.parseInt(lblCant.getText())));
            observableList.add(new Produs(lblNume.getText(), Integer.parseInt(lblPret.getText()), Integer.parseInt(lblCant.getText())));
            table.setItems(observableList);
        }catch (ValidationException e){
            showAllert(e);
        }
    }
    public void clickDelete(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            Produs p = new Produs(lblNume.getText(), Integer.parseInt(lblPret.getText()), Integer.parseInt(lblCant.getText()));
            service.deleteProduct(p);
            observableList.clear();
            observableList = FXCollections.observableList(StreamSupport.stream(service.getAllProducts().spliterator(), false).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            table.setItems(observableList);
        }catch (ValidationException e){
            showAllert(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        colNume.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<model.Produs,String>("denumire"));
        colPret.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<model.Produs,Integer>("pret"));
        colCantitate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<model.Produs,Integer>("cantitate"));

    }

    public void onPretChange(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Produs, ?> pretIntegerCellEditEvent) {

        try{
            Produs produs=table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            produs.setPret((Integer) pretIntegerCellEditEvent.getNewValue());
            service.updateProdus(produs);}
        catch (NumberFormatException e){
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("EroareMare");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Pretul trebuie sa fie un numar natural");
            DialogPane dialogPane = alert.getDialogPane();
            dialogPane.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/cssDesign/myDialogs.css").toExternalForm());
            dialogPane.getStyleClass().add("myDialog");
            dialogPane.setHeader(null);
            alert.show();
        }
    }

    public void onCantitateChange(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Produs, Integer> pretIntegerCellEditEvent) {

        try{
            Produs produs=table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            produs.setCantitate(pretIntegerCellEditEvent.getNewValue());
            service.updateProdus(produs);}
        catch (NumberFormatException e){
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("EroareMare");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Cantitatea trebuie sa fie un numar natural");
            DialogPane dialogPane = alert.getDialogPane();
            dialogPane.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/cssDesign/myDialogs.css").toExternalForm());
            dialogPane.getStyleClass().add("myDialog");
            dialogPane.setHeader(null);
            alert.show();
        }
    }


private void showAllert(ValidationException e){
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Eroare");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText(e.getMessage());
        DialogPane dialogPane = alert.getDialogPane();     
 dialogPane.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/cssDesign/myDialogs.css").toExternalForm());
        dialogPane.getStyleClass().add("myDialog");
        dialogPane.setHeader(null);
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:983)
        at javafx.base/javafx.util.converter.IntegerStringConverter.fromString(IntegerStringConverter.java:49)
        at javafx.base/javafx.util.converter.IntegerStringConverter.fromString(IntegerStringConverter.java:35)
        at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.cell.CellUtils.lambda$createTextField$1(CellUtils.java:255)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8865)
        at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior.fire(TextFieldBehavior.java:184)
        at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.lambda$keyMapping$62(TextInputControlBehavior.java:330)
        at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:4083)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1600(Scene.java:4029)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2146)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2620)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:217)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:149)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$1(GlassViewEventHandler.java:248)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:547)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:971)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Comment: The first line indicates that it is a `NumberFormatException` for input String 'a' which means you have entered a non number character (__a__ in this case) and it was not handled.

Comment: The `IntegerStringConverter` doesn't handles the `NumberFormatException` by default, create your own `StringConverter` where you can handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom `IntegerStringConverter` in your ControllerAdmin class:

```
public static class CustomIntegerStringConverter extends IntegerStringConverter {
    private final IntegerStringConverter converter = new IntegerStringConverter();

    @Override
    public String toString(Integer object) {
        try {
            return converter.toString(object);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            showAlert(e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer fromString(String string) {
        try {
            return converter.fromString(string);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            showAlert(e);
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it the same way as `IntegerStringConverter`:

```
colPret.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new CustomIntegerStringConverter()));
colCantitate.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new CustomIntegerStringConverter()));
```

And make `showAlert()` take an `Exception` as a parameter instead of ValidationException:

```
private void showAlert(Exception e){
    /* show an alret */
}
```